# How to get the energy information

Tags: centos, sensors

I am a student. My teacher requests me to get the energy information of servers. I have seen some tips but they does not work. 
I am using Centos7, and I do not have the file /sys/class/power_supply/.....It is so bad. What should I do?

Comment: Does "energy" mean watts? Btu?

Comment: yes,just as watts and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what do you mean by energy information but I strongly recommend you to read the [official Power Management Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/index.html) from RHEL 6. There, they mention some tools that may help you, such as `powertop` or `blt` for example.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: power top can not acquire the energy information.The energy information is for example power or eneygy...Is anything should I do?or my server can not acquire the energy information because of lack of some sensors ?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if `lm_sensors` is installed.

```
yum list lm_sensors
```

If `lm_sensors` is installed you can use the command below to show voltages:

```
sensors
```

If `lm_sensors` is not installed, you may be able to install it using:

```
sudo yum install lm_sensors
```

To initialize it:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Comment: I have installed sensor.

Comment: [root@controller intel-rapl]# sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +94.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +94.0°C)
Core 1:         +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +94.0°C)
Core 2:         +44.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +94.0°C)
Core 3:         +43.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +94.0°C)
or my server can not acquire the energy information because of lack of some sensors ?